# buttons are like one, when i click either button they both do the same thing

Tags: javascript, html, css

why isn't it not working when I press the previous button, it's like both the previous and next button are the same

here's the code:
https://codepen.io/pinkypink/pen/NWjzMre

```
const images = document.querySelector('.carousel_images');
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel_button');

const imageCount = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel_images img').length;
let imageIndex = 1;
let translateX = 0;

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (e.target.id === 'next') {
      if (imageIndex !== 1) {
        imageIndex--;
        translateX += 650;
      }
    } else {
      if (imageIndex !== imageCount) {
        imageIndex++;
        translateX -= 683;
      }
    }
    
    images.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}px)`;
  });
});
```

Comment: `console.log(e.target.id);` = ""

Comment: @RobMoll it just returns the increments like when i click it goes up by 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `e.currentTarget` not `e.target`.

`e.target` is the element that was clicked - in your case the SVG element.

`e.currentTarget` is the element whose event listener is being called - in your case the div.

Answer (score 2):

What I am pointing out in the comment is that if you add the `console...` statement, you will see that `e.target.id` returns an empty string ("").

Therefore, the if statement becomes

```
if ("" === 'next') {
```

which will always be false so the `else` statement runs which is the `previous` button.

```
buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if ("" === 'next') {  <-------------------------------------
      if (imageIndex !== 1) {
        imageIndex--;
        translateX += 650;
      }
    } else {
      if (imageIndex !== imageCount) {
        imageIndex++;
        translateX -= 683;
      }
    }
    
    images.style.transform = `translateX(${translateX}px)`;
  });
});
```

This answers your question: *why isn't it working when I press the previous button, it's like both the previous and next button are the same*